# How to call a method from a class given that I have the Constructor for it?

Tags: java, object, constructor

If I have a constructor object `Constructor<?> productConstructor`, how can I call the `run()` method that exists in that class?

For example, let's say I have the class:

```java
public class product1{
    public product1(Instances instance){
       // constructor
    }

    public void run(){
       // do something
    }
}
```

I can run the constructor for my class like this:

```
Constructor<?> productConstructor;
productConstructor = getProductConstructor(instance.getProductName());
// pass instance into constructor to run the tests
// example of what is happening here -> new product1(instance)
productConstructor.newInstance(new Object[] { instance });
```

```java
public Constructor<?> getProductConstructor(String productName) {
    try {
        logger.info("Looking for Product Class: {}", productName);
        String fullQualifiedClassPath = "com.products." + productName;
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(fullQualifiedClassPath);
        return clazz.getConstructor(Instances.class);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Product: {} does not exist", productName);
    }
    return null;
}
```

If I keep the code as is, then I have to place the `run()` method inside of the constructor to run it, but I would like the `run()` method outside of the constructor. How can I call my run method using the Constructor class for my class?

For example, something like this is what I had in mind but doesn't work:

```java
Constructor<?> productConstructor;
productConstructor = getProductConstructor(instance.getProductName());
productConstructor.newInstance(new Object[] { instance }).run(); // added .run() to the end but this doesn't work.
```

This doesn't work because `run` is undefined. This is because I cannot call a method this way on a class that is not known until runtime. This is where my problem lies.

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Calss names should start with uppercase character

Comment: Does the caller know about the `product1` class?

Comment: *but this doesn't work* is not an error description. If you get an error, post the stacktrace. or describe what is not working means

Comment: In my code it does have proper naming conventions, my bad, I just changed code as to not give out sensitive data for work

Comment: By doesn't work I mean that `run` is undefined. That's because it doesn't actually know what class I have until run time

Comment: Maybe have it implement `Runnable` and do a cast to `Runnable` and call `run()`? That said, without some context why are what you're trying to do, this sounds a bit like an X-Y problem.

Comment: We have a server that we drop files into. Based on the file name, we run different product scripts. So if the file is "m_product1.csv", then I want to run the class's run method like: `new product1().run()`

Comment: Note that since Java 8, you can make this much cleaner, more reliable, and more flexible by replacing your reflection code with `Function<Instances, Product> f = Product::new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it like this:

```
Constructor<?> productConstructor;
Class<?> productClass;
productConstructor = getProductConstructor(instance.getProductName());
productClass = getProductClass(instance.getProductName());
productClass.getMethod("run").invoke(productConstructor.newInstance(new Object[] { instance }));

    public Constructor<?> getProductConstructor(String productName) {
        try {
            String fullQualifiedClassPath = "com.products." + productName;
            logger.info("Looking for Product Constructor: {}", fullQualifiedClassPath);
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(fullQualifiedClassPath);
            return clazz.getConstructor(Instances.class);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Product: {} does not exist", productName);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Class<?> getProductClass(String productName) {
        try {
            String fullQualifiedClassPath = "com.products." + productName;
            logger.info("Looking for Product Class: {}", fullQualifiedClassPath);
            return Class.forName(fullQualifiedClassPath);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Product: {} does not exist", productName);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `productConstructor.newInstance(new Object[] { instance });` retrieves an `Object` and you have to cast it to the required type `product1`:

```java
((product1)productConstructor.newInstance(new Object[] { instance })).run();
```

---

Let me offer you one of my projects [reflection-utils](https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/reflection-utils).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ru.oleg-cherednik.utils.reflection</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflection-utils</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
product1 product1 = ConstructorUtils.invokeConstructor(product1.class, Instances.class, new Instances());
product1.run();
```

---

In case you cannot include the file (e.g. file has package visibility), you can do the same using names:

```java
String className = "com.products.product1";
Object product1 = ConstructorUtils.invokeConstructor(className, Instance.class, new Instance());

String methodName = "run";
MethodUtils.invokeMethod(product1, methodName);
```

You can find more examples of how to use reflection there.

Comment: That was I was afraid of. with this solution I still have to import the class so that I can use it and cast. I guess ill just stick with running `run` from the constructor.

Comment: @mcool You could always just assume the `run` method exists and try to reflectively invoke it (e.g. `theClass.getMethod("run").invoke(theInstance)`).

Comment: That was exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: @mcool you can check my lib. There is an example how easily call a method by method name. I give a snippet here later today